# How to realize this js encrypt script in python?

Tags: python-3.x, password-encryption, login-script

Recently I am doing something like auto-login with python, but i am a freshman in this area.

I want to login to www.jd.com, and after fetch the post data with Chrome, I found this

```
uuid:37ac1f08-0ed9-4e0d-a424-76c31d566915
eid:ZLTFMPUYPUVH3AQWGB3I4YEJ5YR4EQLSXV7YKAX27FNOY3CPTY37EVDW755A2DUGP6GKOFADCU7JKKYCAMYM3QHAS4
fp:b871dc2da5cf2bf85a6a5a56259e28e3
_t:_ntscXrr
loginType:f
loginname:xxxxxxx
nloginpwd:RAc2wPFCr7jwP5ocHh295pGBuZL9xUYzlWh108xqsp6o90x6KiHVTbw3Yn6NRz8YMDp%2BOHlT58oinO%2FuLwvysmD3XKazm0MYEulWseG2gotduYTywA6%2FrO1hUskfVjHuPoLu8r3stjNRQ0dnKF%2BvIxganMiDEUTiUmliAGQqnWc%3D
chkRememberMe:
authcode:
pubKey:MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDC7kw8r6tq43pwApYvkJ5laljaN9BZb21TAIfT%2FvexbobzH7Q8SUdP5uDPXEBKzOjx2L28y7Xs1d9v3tdPfKI2LR7PAzWBmDMn8riHrDDNpUpJnlAGUqJG9ooPn8j7YNpcxCa1iybOlc2kEhmJn5uwoanQq%2BCA6agNkqly2H4j6wIDAQAB
sa_token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
seqSid:1777115819395099100
```

Here the password is encrypted, and later I found this js code

```
function getEntryptPwd(pwd){
    var pubKey = $('#pubKey').val();
    if(!pwd || !pubKey || !SysConfig.encryptInfo){
        return pwd;
    }
    var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
    encrypt.setPublicKey(pubKey);
    return encrypt.encrypt(pwd);
}
```

However, I don't know how to do the same thing in python, could anyone please tell me how to this?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

here is my way to encrypt the password using pubkey you get from the html.

1. Request the login url to get the pubkey (also other informations).
2. Install a third-party module rsa.

   pip install rsa
3. Run the following script to encrypt your password based on pubkey.

And you can find my code [here](https://github.com/leeleeee/awseome-login/tree/master/004_jd). :)

```
<input type="hidden" name="pubKey" id="pubKey" value="MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDC7kw8r6tq43pwApYvkJ5laljaN9BZb21TAIfT/vexbobzH7Q8SUdP5uDPXEBKzOjx2L28y7Xs1d9v3tdPfKI2LR7PAzWBmDMn8riHrDDNpUpJnlAGUqJG9ooPn8j7YNpcxCa1iybOlc2kEhmJn5uwoanQq+CA6agNkqly2H4j6wIDAQAB" class="hide"/>

(admin) $ cat encrypt.py 
import rsa
import base64
import os

def bytes2hex(s):
    return s.decode() 

def bytes2base64(s):
    return bytes2hex(base64.standard_b64encode(s))

class RSA():

    def __init__(self):
        # self.pubkey = self.load_pub_key(pubkey) if pubkey else None
        self.pubkey = None
        pass

    def form_pem_pub_key(self, keystr,):
        """
        Fortmat a public key string to PEM format, in which start with
        BEGIN PUBLIC KEY and end with END PUBLIC KEY.
        Parameters:
        keystr -- the public key string of PEM-encoded(base64)
        Returns:
               -- Formatted public key string
        """
        import textwrap
        line_len = 64
        begin = ['-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----']
        end = ['-----END PUBLIC KEY-----']
        return '\n'.join(begin + textwrap.wrap(keystr, line_len) + end) 

    def check_pem_key_str(self, keystr,):
        return False
        pass


    def load_pem_pub_key(self, pubkey,):
        if isinstance(pubkey, str):
            keystr = pubkey if self.check_pem_key_str(pubkey) else self.form_pem_pub_key(pubkey)
        self.pubkey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1_openssl_pem(keystr)

    def encrypt(self, msg):
        if not self.pubkey:
            raise ValueError('Pubic key is empty, please load it first.')
        # convert string or other type to bytes 
        msg = msg if isinstance(msg, bytes) else str(msg).encode()
        return bytes2base64(rsa.encrypt(msg, self.pubkey))

def encrypt_password(pubkey, password):
    rsa = RSA()
    rsa.load_pem_pub_key(pubkey)
    return rsa.encrypt(password)

password = 'test'
pubkey = 'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDC7kw8r6tq43pwApYvkJ5laljaN9BZb21TAIfT/vexbobzH7Q8SUdP5uDPXEBKzOjx2L28y7Xs1d9v3tdPfKI2LR7PAzWBmDMn8riHrDDNpUpJnlAGUqJG9ooPn8j7YNpcxCa1iybOlc2kEhmJn5uwoanQq+CA6agNkqly2H4j6wIDAQAB'

print(encrypt_password(pubkey, password))

(admin) $ python encrypt.py 
nQJvsRspY+zAnywU9YsSTNHb/OoNOLLbADsenBwOlDHnv//UUPpBidA4n4pN7Frm0iIRQAJT1hRNAu/tASZjihtWiOYuwD+XFos2Tmk+SLRIc6VvqvAL9CJFLrzbIS3tgbx9vkyM30Qy6ENFOyOcpR7nV93xY82F1dB7bRsuNGU=
```